# Typescript: How to extract the value types of a const object and use them as keys in a new type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, partial

I want to take a constant object, say `{key1: 'value1', key2: value2'} as const`, and convert its values into keys and use it in a new object with type `{value1: number; value2: number}`. I'd like to do this in a function, and I want the function to be typed correctly.

Below is the code that I'm trying to get to work. The error is happening when I try to cast a variable of type `Partial<Blah>` to `Blah`. Could someone explain why it's happening, and if there's a way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

```
type BaseObject = Record<string, string>;


type ValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K]]: number;
};

function useValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T): ValuesAsKeys<T> {
  const x: Partial<ValuesAsKeys<T>> = {};
  for (const value of Object.values(arg) as Array<T[keyof T]>) {
    x[value] = 1;
  }

  // This line doesn't work
  return x as ValuesAsKeys<T>;
}

// Example use case
const obj = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} as const;
const result = useValuesAsKeys(obj); // Type of result is {value1: number; value2: number}


// Everything below here works
// Only including this because I'm contrasting this code with the code above.

type KeysAsKeys<T extends BaseObject> = {
    [K in keyof T]: number;
};

function useKeysAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T): KeysAsKeys<T> {
    const x: Partial<KeysAsKeys<T>> = {};
  for (const value of Object.values(arg) as Array<T[keyof T]>) {
    x[value] = 1;
  }
  return x as KeysAsKeys<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why casting `Partial<Blah>` to `Blah` doesn't work in this scenario, but this code works and is type-safe enough for me:

```
function useValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T): ValuesAsKeys<T> {
  const x = {} as ValuesAsKeys<T>;
  for (const value of Object.values(arg) as Array<T[keyof T]>) {
    x[value] = 1;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicit return type with `reduce` almost always does not work, because `initial` values changes every iteration.

In order to make it work, it is better to overload your function:

```js
type BaseObject = Record<string, string>;


type ValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K]]: number;
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

function useValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T): ValuesAsKeys<T>
function useValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T) {
  return (Object.values(arg) as Array<Values<T>>).reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: 1
  }), {})
}

// Example use case
const obj = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } as const;

const result = useValuesAsKeys(obj); // Type of result is {value1: number; value2: number}
result.value1 //ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgeQEYCsIGNhQLxQBK2A9gE4AmAPAsGQJYB2A5gDRS0MsB8A3AFCDQkKADU4AGwCuEBAEEEAaQggEVACpQIAD2ARGFBLEQoM2YN3xQA3vyhQA2oqhMoAaxUkAZlE2JfTgC6gQBcUIxSALaoEGQCAL4C-MLQ4tKyGpYE6g4eIN6%20gYJeUow49CSMUFJIaTLySipqmjp6BkbwSGiYONwAFHBkzGHqAJRhdbIKyqqZ-CVlwBVVNRCTDTPNWrr6hsZdZr0DQyOjNnZQZBDAUmRVfd3mAHQAbpL1x8xn-nJkZHAgKjrTLcUZPK4UKRYCB9AZYLDsCASCCRM54Sx9Wz2exPXFweGsC72BxIlGhKAARgu8VG7GsNP48UEAHpmVAAKLaOCRMDI6pIKBYEz8LCVWhQEgYKzWdwqClhADkb3SFIV7DyACZFcqZBqFVB4lB-KLGLQkibxVcEFIJLgCKt1tMmn1JehRrwoKzfOBoAUrTbcPQjNYdRB5eEojE4lBQ1qI9FYkz-bbXu8w57mSQ3PwgA)

[docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Comment: I'm not a fan of function overloading in this case because typescript seems to miss obvious errors. For example, using a `string` return value as an overload goes undetected:

`function useValuesAsKeys<T extends BaseObject>(arg: T): string`

Comment: @Eric Chen No problem)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to accomplish that.

```
const obj = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' } as const;

type ValuesAsKeys = typeof obj[keyof typeof obj];

const myUseOfObject: { [key in ValuesAsKeys]: number } = {
    value1: 1,
    value2: 2
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).